# NPM peer dependency on JQuery OR Zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, zepto, npmjs

My problem is fairly simple: I'm working on a front-end development framework that is currently dependent on a few pieces of JQuery. However, with NPM it seems that it makes more sense to have a peer dependency, so that we can just use whatever version of JQuery our users have installed.

The thing is, Zepto is also sufficient for this project, and is much friendlier to mobile and embedded developers due to its smaller size.

My question, then, is if it's possible to have a peer dependency that requires either JQuery OR Zepto, and if so, how. Or, should I simply include the peer dependency to JQuery and document that Zepto users can ignore the warning?